# Getting "export PATH" to stick

Tags: bash, osx-lion, path

I just upgraded to Lion and I am using bash for the first time (my previous experience is with csh and tcsh).  I have encountered unexpected behavior.  A simple example is:

1. I create a file containing the following commands:

   ```
   echo PATH BEFORE is $PATH
   PATH=/usr/local/fortran:$PATH
   export PATH
   echo PATH AFTER is $PATH
   ```
2. I open a terminal (in bash) and execute the file shown above.  It echoes the expected result:

   ```
   PATH BEFORE is /usr/bin: ...
   PATH AFTER is /usr/local/fortran:/usr/bin ...
   ```
3. I then type:

   ```
   echo $PATH
   ```

   and `/usr/local/fortran` is NOT part of the path.  I assumed that the export command would make the PATH sticky.  Can someone explain why this is not happening?

Answer (score 6):

You need to *source* the file so that the *exported* variables are accessible to the current shell.

```
source script-file
echo $PATH
```

… or add the `export` command to one of bash's configuration files — In OS X, that'd typically be `.bash_profile`.

Comment: @DMF If you want it to stick for every terminal session, see my update to the answer.

Comment: This is for code that I am embedding in a GUI.  I don't (and don't want to) alter things that .bash_profile.  Instead, I want to execute that change in $PATH only for the present shell.  So, the "source" approach solves the problem.

Comment: @DMF Alright. Make sure you accept Prince John Wesley's answer by clicking the checkmark next to it! :)

Answer (score 1):

Put

```
PATH=/usr/local/fortran:$PATH
export PATH
```

in your .bash_profile file.

How do you execute the file containing the command ? Try sourceing  it with `source` (man source)